# Using SSH on windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, ssh, putty, windows-server-2012

I have Windows 2012 R2 server and I have some commands and operations to execute over there concerning a service that runs permanently.

My PC is using Windows 10 which has the feature of OpenSSH builtin, so I have the `ssh` command available.

If I undestand it, I could be able to access the Windows server, but can't figure that out. How can I access remotely the server to issue commands?

Is it better to stand with the PuTTY solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I undestand it well, I could be able to access the Windows server, but can't figure that out. How can I access remotely the server to issue commands?

Yes, but you have to **install** some SSH server first, because Windows Server 2012 *did not* come with any SSH software built-in.

You can try installing either [OpenSSH for Windows](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases) (not sure if it is compatible with Win2012), or [Bitvise SSH Server](https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-server) (which has a free version for personal use), or something else [from this 2015 thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/8411/what-is-a-good-ssh-server-to-use-on-windows).

Windows Server 2012 also supports WinRM "PowerShell Remoting", which can be used instead of SSH.

> Is it better to stand with the PuTTY solution?

Doesn't matter. Both are SSH clients. Both will connect you to an SSH server. Your current problem is with the *server*, not with the client.

Comment: If i go through WinRM, I need to get it enabled through GPO, isn't that right?

Comment: @Eug_Zazou - Windows Server isn’t typically managed by a group policy itself.  Since we are clearly talking about a corporate network you should contact your network administrator or whomever is responsible for the configuration of the server

Comment: @Eug_Zazou: Not WinRM itself, but yes, you will probably need to enable CredSSP (i.e. password-based authentication) through GPO on the client. By default it only allows Kerberos.

Comment: Install OpenSSH for Windows and then start service with `Start-Service sshd`. The OpenSSH folder should be on PATH. Indications on [microsoft-openssh_install](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse?tabs=powershell)